# Another Netbeans issue | cannot find symbol method, but correctly declared

Tags: java, ide, compiler-errors, netbeans6.7

this has been a crappy day, besides the IDE not compiling/deploying because of [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386076/uncompilable-source-code-runtimeexception-in-netbeans) and waisting valuable time, I finally get it to deploy it suddenly I start getting this weird message (after compiling and running it several times):
`T:\Users\Triztian\Documents\RHT System\RHTUBSDB\src\java\controllers\OrderSearch.java:64: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method metadata(java.lang.Long)
location: class BO.CoverForm
            OrderExtraInfoDTO foundInformation = frmCover.metadata(foundOrder.getReferenceNumber());`
it is my understanding that this means that my method isn't declared, but thats not the situation as my method is clearly declared and coded.

**CoverForm.java**:

```
public OrderExtraInfoDTO metadata(Long ReferenceNumber) {
        OrderExtraInfoDTO foundInformation = new OrderExtraInfoDTO();
        try{
            foundInformation =  lnkAddInformation.fetchInformation(ReferenceNumber);
        } catch (DAOException daoe) {
            this.setError("additional_information", daoe.getMessage());
        }
        return foundInformation;
    }
```

And the servlet that calls the CoverForm.java method.

**OrderSearch.java** (Extends HttpServlet):

```
  CoverDTO foundCover = frmCover.search(foundOrder.getReferenceNumber());
            OrderExtraInfoDTO foundInformation = frmCover.metadata(foundOrder.getReferenceNumber());
            UpgradesDTO foundUpgrades = frmUpgrades.search(foundOrder.getReferenceNumber());
```

I've tried renaming the method and didn't have any success, any help is truly appreciated as I'm getting frustrated with NB 6.9.1 because of some crashes and another weird bug (might catch an entomologist's attention) which locks the editor and displays a message saying: "Refactoring cannot be done in the given context" whenever I press delete, forcing me to restart the IDE.

---

**EDIT**

Ok, so I've removed the classes that I posted and merged them in a more appropriate place, however I still get that silly symbol not found error but on a different symbol(another method) this time.

Comment: Hello again! The step that remains would be to check the external libraries you are using. Since you have made a new installation, the jars that are included with the package should be ok. In order to check out the libraries make a new project and write a couple of mickey-mouse programs and make sure they work right.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans 6.9.1 is a very robust IDE. You may run into problems like the one you mention above, if:

1. You run your NB without enough disk space available. Make sure that you have at least 2 GB free on your file system for the necessary temporary files.
2. You have a very large number of projects active in your project space. Reduce this number to just the needed projects, by deleting and reopening more often.

Hope this helps ...

Comment: I don't think thats the problem, I have over 400 Gb in disk space and just 1 project file, but thanks for the help.

Comment: In that case, check to see whether you have a number of stray running projects that occupy a lot of memory. A final option would be to try a fresh installation of NB.

Comment: I've also reinstalled netbeans, downloaded the latest from their website and I have only developed one project on this machine, it seems that my particular project triggers all of these bugs because I migrated the project to a laptop an had the same issue, tried deleting the build directories (only leaving `/src` and `/web`) still same bug.

Comment: It is possible that one or more of your build*.xml files is broken. Set up a new project and create the problematic classes again manually. Then copy and paste the source from the classes in the old project into them.

Comment: Yep, I've started a new project and copied the src and web folders into it, still no success...

Comment: It is better to avoid refactoring copy from the kaput version to the new one.

Comment: hmm, so I'll do the same , but this time will be copy/paste the text content, I'll create each file again..., I'm reintstalling NB again..