# First Web application with Intellij

Tags: jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea

I decided to switch from NetBeans 6.9.1 as  it gave [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386076/uncompilable-source-code-runtimeexception-in-netbeans) and the fix isn't working, so instead of wasting more time I decided to switch to to Intellij 9 Ultimate. The problem is that I'm having a hard time finding a good starters guide for developing/deploying/running and debugging a web applications using JSP + JSTL + apache-tomcat 6.0.29 after being familiar to the netbeans environment. I have the project set up, I believe I can start the server too, how ever, I get the message `"cannot open URL"` when I press the green play button. Any help is really appreciated or any links besides the manual what would be perfect is a complete "Guide for dummies" for a simple hello world example.