# JavaCV/OpenCV: cvLoadImage not working

Tags: java, javacv

I installed the JavaCV/OpenCV libraries, and I'm having a problem with the basic example code.

According to several examples that I have looked at, this code should load an image:

```
IplImage image = cvLoadImage("C:\\img.jpg");
```

But, when I run that I get a "cannot find symbol" error.

Since this is my first time using it, I'm not sure if I messed the install up or not.

According to the newest JavaCV readme, I do have the correct version of OpenCV. I also have all the JavaCV jar files imported. As far as I can tell, I also have all the paths set correctly too.

Anyone know what the problem is?

Edit:

Full code:

```
import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
import java.io.File;


public class demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        IplImage image = cvLoadImage("C:\\img.jpg");

        final CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("Demo");
        canvas.showImage(image);
        canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

Error when I try to run it:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: cvLoadImage
    at javacv.demo.main(demo.java:17)

Java Result: 1

Seems like it is claiming cvLoadImage doesn't take a string as an argument.

Comment: Please submit more log file so that we can help you

Comment: Edited and added the full program plus the error message. That is the only error it throws.

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333285/java-lang-runtimeexception-uncompilable-source-code-what-can-cause-this and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386076/uncompilable-source-code-runtimeexception-in-netbeans ?

Comment: Just tried it. It didn't change anything. I'm getting the same error.

Comment: are you working on netbeans?

Comment: Yes. Did I miss something when setting it up?

Comment: Please can you submit the class incl. package name and all imports? did you have another classes/packages in your project?

Comment: Here is the class file: https://gist.github.com/xRedactedx/5332779  It is the only class in the project.

Comment: Try my post and let me know about the result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A walk around that i find for you is to load the image by ImageIO and passe it later to `IplImage`

e.g.:

```
 BufferedImage img =  ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\img.jpg") );
 IplImage origImg = IplImage.createFrom(img);
```

Comment: ImageIO.read("C:\\img.jpg")  says: no suitable method found for read(String)   I think maybe I messed up the install somewhere.

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks for the help. Any idea why the other won't work? CanvasFrame is loading from cv library, so it must be working.

Comment: Not exactly. Any there is sometimes problems between the Filenames according to ASCII, UTF-8 and i18n

Answer (score 4):

This solved my problem: `import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgcodecs.*;`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @JoeTaras This is not a question. I wonder what makes you think that. Perhaps you misclicked.

Comment: @Chris This is an attempt at an answer and not a comment. It would have been nice to see a description why this would solve the problem, but still, it's an answer.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I try to respond, your answer does not respond to the question. Your problem can be different of problem of  Lucas.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add this import statement:
    `import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgcodecs.cvLoadImage;`
This is required so that the static method `cvLoadImage` can be used without using the class name.

Answer (score 2):

You have to `import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;`

Answer (score 2):

With javacv 0,9 you have to `import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_highgui.*;`

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error then, i imported the following package, problem solved.

`import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;`

Answer (score 1):

This might be old but for those who stumbled upon this problem like me just now,
here is how I solved it and why:

First OP's error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: cvLoadImage at javacv.demo.main(demo.java:17)

This indicates that the compiler cannot find the cvLoadImage method that you are trying to call.

cvLoadImage is a static method under JavaCPP.
Specifically it is a static method under opencv_imgcodecs class.

To solve this issue one must first specify the import of the opencv_imgcodecs class.

This can be done by adding the import: 
**import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgcodecs.cvLoadImage;**

This in turn would result for the opencv_imgcodecs class to be usable within your class along with its static methods and other functions.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem recently.
if you are using javacv-0.10 (more recent at the moment), import manually this one:

```
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_highgui.*;
```

but the source of JRE of the project should be higher than 1.5

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem happened when the squeegee in debug mode.
Try to run in normal mode.