# Why does NetBeans recreate "old" packages' folders on deploy?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, netbeans, ide

Working with a java web application in NetBeans I've refactored my packages several times. Now when the IDE builds the project, I find empty folders with the names of "old" packages in `build\web\WEB-INF\classes\`. Saying "old" I mean those packages I have already deleted, moved or renamed.

I've looked through all the files in the application folder, searching for these "old" names, but failed to find any occurance at all. Where does NetBeans take it from?

I should add, that these folders are created on *Deploy* command, not *Build*. So probably it's Apache Tomcat...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examining the output window of the IDE, I found that while deploying it used configuration from `c:\Users\<current user>\.netbeans\7.0\var\`. In this directory I found `cache` folder and removed it. Also I deleted my project's `build` folder.

After rebuilding and deploying, IDE created folders for the existing packages only. I do hope that this is it and those old ones were stored in the IDE cache I deleted.

P.S.: before removing the `cache` folder, one should close the IDE, or it may have problems while closing the open solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with this before. If clean and build doesn't fix it. I am sure creating a new project and moving all your .form and .java files from SRC into your new projects SRC will fix it.

I am not sure why netbeans does that but it is finicky when editing Package folders because netbeans needs this written down somewhere in its program to compile from CMD Line and all that jazz.