# Why does this throw an InterruptedException?

Tags: java, multithreading, loops

[image]

This code should compile, should it not?  What am I doing wrong?   I would like the code to briefly pause before displaying each number in the array.

```
public static void median(int odd[]) throws InterruptedException {

    Arrays.sort(odd);

    for (int i = 0; i < odd.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(odd[i]);
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
    System.out.println("The median number of the previous list of numbers is: " + odd[5]);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it compiles. Review a tutorial about checked exceptions. Those must be declared as thrown or caught.

Comment: **Did** it throw the exception, or are you concerned that you have to still address the exception?

Comment: @Makoto  I just want the thing to run!  It wont.  I updated the post with the error netbeans is giving me.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386076/uncompilable-source-code-runtimeexception-in-netbeans

Comment: @tbodt:  It'd be better to close the question as a duplicate instead, then.

Comment: @Makoto Not necessarily. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20183224/1455016.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that in your `main` you have something like

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int[] array  = new int[X];
    ...// populate array
    median(array);
}
```

Because `median` is a method declared as throwing a checked exception, you must either catch the `Exception` or rethrow it.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int[] array  = new int[X];
    ...// populate array
    try {
        median(array);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // handle it
    }
}
```

or

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    int[] array  = new int[X];
    ...// populate array
    median(array);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use try catch block for `Thread.sleep`

Remove the throw exceptions and change

```
Thread.sleep(500);
```

to

```
try{Thread.sleep(500);}catch(Exception e){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Timer` or `TimerTask` instead of making the thread sleep.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely convinced that the exception is thrown, but the reason you have to either declare it to be thrown, or catch it yourself, is due to it being a [checked exception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#Checked_exceptions).

Because `InterruptedException` is declared as part of the signature of the method, you **must** address it in some way.