# Missing Method body, or declare abstract

Tags: java, netbeans

I am getting this error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: Pet.saySomething
>       at PetTest.main(PetTest.java:18)
>   Java Result: 1

Here is what i have: for the `Speak` class,

```
public class Speak {
   public void saySomething();
}
```

Here is what i have in the `PetTest` class:

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class PetTest {

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         ArrayList<Pet> myPets = new ArrayList<Pet>();

         myPets.add(new Parrot("Boss"));
         myPets.add(new Cat("Oreo"));
         myPets.add(new Dog("Riley"));

         for (Pet p: myPets)
         {
             p.saySomething();
             System.out.println(p);
         }
     }
 }
```

I did not post the other 5 classes that go with this program. I know there is something that needs to be fixed in the `Speak` class, but i am stuck. In the `Speak` class, on the line that says `public void saySomething();` it says Missing Method body, or declare abstract.

EDIT: Here are the other classes:

```
 public abstract class Pet {

     String name;

     public Pet(String name){
         this.name = name;
     }
 }

 public class Parrot extends Bird {

     public Parrot (String name)
     {
         super(name);
     }

     @Override
     public void saySomething()
     {
         System.out.println("Pauly want a craker?");
     }

     @Override
     public String toString()
     {
         return "Hello, I'm " + name + " the parrot.";
     }

 }


 public class Dog extends Pet {

     public Dog (String name)
     {
         super(name);
     }

     @Override
     public void saySomething()
     {
         System.out.println("Ruff, ruff!");
     }

     @Override
     public String toString()
     {
         return "Hello, I'm " + name + " the dog.";
     }
 }


 public class Cat extends Pet {

     public Cat(String name)
     {
         super(name);
     }

     @Override
     public void saySomething()
     {
    System.out.println("Meow.");
     }

     @Override
     public String toString()
     {
         return "Hello, I'm " + name + " the cat.";
     }
 }

 public class Bird extends Pet {

     public Bird(String name)
     {
         super(name);
     }

     public void saySomething(){}

 }
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you using Netbeans?

Comment: Then you may want to check this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4386076/1065197

Comment: i checked that one out, still having the same issue, however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following options for Speak, take your pick:

**1st**

```
public abstract class Speak{

   public abstract void saySomething();

}
```

**2nd**

```
public class Speak{

   public void saySomething(){

   }
}
```

**3rd**

```
public interface Speak{

   public void saySomething();
}
```

**Edit**: First of all, you are not using Speak class anywhere. Second, please add the following method in Pet class:

```
 public abstract void saySomething();
```

Comment: I tried all 3 of those choice, but i am still receiving Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: Pet.saySomething
 at PetTest.main(PetTest.java:18)
Java Result: 1

Comment: That worked perfectly. As you can tell i am no expert in java. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

If `Speak` is a concrete class, it must implement all of its methods, so `saySomething` must have a body.

However, it looks like `Speak` is more suitable to be an interface. Your `Pet` class can implement that interface.