# Netbeans 8.2 Java: Uncompilable code trying to access java.awt.Shape.contains()

Tags: java, netbeans, iterator, awt, shapes

Working on Netbeans 8.2 in Java, and Iḿ encountering an error I can't quite make sense of.

I'm trying to check whether a Shape object was clicked on or not, and then remove it from my list of Shape objects (hence the use of iterator). But something is causing a problem that prevents Shape.contain(Point p) from working, giving me this error message:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.util.Iterator.contains
>   ...

What is the problem here? Shouldn't contains() work like this? What am I missing?

Complete Code:

```
    public DuckHuntPanel() {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        shapes = new ArrayList<>();
        shapes.add(ball);
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000 / 60, (ActionListener) this);
        timer.start();
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
                super.mouseClicked(me);
                Iterator<Shape> shape = shapes.iterator();
                while (shape.hasNext()) {
                    shape.next();
                    if (shape.contains(me.getPoint())) { // <- This causes error 
                        if (isDuck) {
                            score++;
                        } else {
                            score--;
                            shape.remove();
                        }
                        isDuck = !isDuck;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386076/uncompilable-source-code-runtimeexception-in-netbeans

Comment: Btw shouldn't be `if (shape.next().contains`? The `Iterator` object don't have the `contains` method, the `Shape` object returned by `shape.next()` has it. In that case you should remove the line 'shape.next();' since you'll move to the next object inside the `if` or modify the entire code accordingly.

Comment: @easyjoin.net I tried, but I'm unable to locate the files, as the location seems to have changed in Netbeans 8.2. Any tips on where to find them?
(yes, I'm still new to Netbeans)

Comment: @easyjoin.net OMG, thank you! Now it works.

Comment: Don't add answer in questions. Use the answer field instead to share QA style or if this is a typo, delete this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be `if (shape.next().contains`. The Iterator object don't have the contains method, the `Shape` object returned by `shape.next()` has it. In that case you should remove the line `shape.next();` since you'll move to the next object inside the `if` or modify the entire code accordingly.